# Symfony2: How to hide the seconds in my datetime form input?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have following field configuration in my FormType:

```
$builder
            ->add('startDate','datetime',array(
                'required' => false,
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'time_widget' => 'single_text',
                'with_seconds' => false,
            ))
```

Still the form shows me the time widget with seconds:

> 08:15:00

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score -1):

Set the [date_format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format)-attribute.

Comment: **date_format** somehow only effects the date-field. If you render a **datetime** field into two separate fields, this will not work unfortunately.